# "su - non-root" arises "su sorry"

Tags: command-line, user-account

In Ubuntu I am able to switch of user (to **non**-root) through the terminal executing:

```
su - username
Password:
```

And done. I am able to do anything according the own permissions/roles of the **non**-root user.

But on Mac (El Capitan) - once logged (started the laptop with my normal `Admin` user type) if I try to switch to a **non**-root user through the terminal:

```
su - username
Password:
su: Sorry
```

Why does `su: Sorry` appear? I am absolutely sure the password is correct. What is wrong or missing? FYI The **non**-root user in Mac was created how a `Sharing Only` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [macOS User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-a-sharing-only-user-account-on-mac-mchlp15577/mac) (more specifically the [description of sharing-only users](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/aside/glos8dd1231e/12.0/mac/12.0)):

> Sharing-only users can access shared files remotely, but can’t log in or change settings on the computer.

A sharing user has neither a home directory (run `ls /Users` to check) nor a login shell (`dscl . -read /Users/sharingiscaring UserShell` returns `UserShell: /usr/bin/false`).

Comment: Thanks, it was confuse because that user appeared listed through `dscl . list /Users | grep -v '_'` - so I am going to create a new user but being `Standard` type

Comment: the quote note shared does not appear in the link shared, consider to update the link. Thank you

Comment: @ManuelJordan It's in the popup you get when you clikck on "sharing-only user".

Comment: @ManuelJordan All users appear in `dscl ...`:-)